# Set data for Embed Form in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to set data for contact_phone and contact_postal_address type in an embed form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('phone', 'contact_phone')
            ->add('postal', 'contact_postal_address');
    }
```

But as I know, when creating the form, I can set only 1 object for the form like this

```
$form = $this->createForm('address', $address); //address is the embed form
```

How can I do to set data for each child type in address type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form-specific model that you use for this form, for example:

```
class ModelForForm
{
    public $phone;

    public $postal;
}
```

You can add any assertions here as well if you're using annotations, such as `Valid()`.

Then you can populate this new model with your data:

```
$model = new ModelForForm();
$model->postal = $address;
// ...

$form = $this->createForm('address', $model);
```

Make sure you update your form type's `data_class` option to be the name of the class you create above.